# Streaming .wav audio fails, but plays when downloaded separately

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I am having trouble over streaming of wav audio files with androids MediaPlayer.

The URL for wave files are verified and downloaded separately on device successfully.
Those downloaded files plays with no issue, but when same file is streamed to the player, it won't play at all and gives error.

```
01-18 09:25:00.963: E/MediaPlayer(8825): error (1, -4)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at com.movivation.wavetrial.AudioPlayer.playMedia(AudioPlayer.java:174)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at com.movivation.wavetrial.AudioPlayer.onCreate(AudioPlayer.java:92)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
01-18 09:25:00.963: W/System.err(8825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 09:25:00.973: W/System.err(8825):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-18 09:25:00.973: W/System.err(8825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-18 09:25:00.973: W/System.err(8825):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-18 09:25:00.973: W/System.err(8825):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 09:25:00.973: I/MediaPlayer(8825): Info (1,26)
```

My code to play the file:

```
private void playMedia(boolean isWebUrl) {
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.d(tag, "Ending thread");
            isPlaying = false;
            if (pd != null) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.d(tag, "starting");

            mPlayer.start();
            mSeekbar.setProgress(0);
            mSeekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());

            Log.d(tag, "seek started");
            new PlayAsync().execute();
        }
    });

    mSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                mSeekbar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        if (isWebUrl) {
            Log.d(tag, "playing tmp file");
            mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } else {
            File f = new File(fileurl);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
        }

        Log.d(tag, "calling prepare");
        mPlayer.prepare(); //originally i use prepareAsync()
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The file I am trying to play is actually a wave file, and I have not found any concrete statement about the error mentioned above.

Any pointer regarding streaming of wave or the error itself would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Question edited with sample snippet. Though i have used prepare() method for catching the exception temporarily, but actually i use prepareasync() method.

Comment: Could you highlight this point in your code? "at com.movivation.wavetrial.AudioPlayer.playMedia(AudioPlayer.java:174)"

Comment: it points to `mPlayer.prepare();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this guy seems to do what you want. Let's have a look: http://code.google.com/p/rxwen-blog-stuff/source/browse/trunk/android/streaming_audio/

Comment: I am getting some noise as output following the main file w.r.t your link above

Comment: well...both. In my case if its making sound means it is able to read the file from the stream(better than mediaplayer). But again the problem starts when i realize that i have no idea how to proceed next because AudioTrack is entirely  manual way of playing audio content bytes by bytes.... about which i have no clue.

Comment: Let's try using mPlayer.reset() just before mPlayer.setDataSource(...).